# What should I consider when deleting an AUR package?

Tags: arch-linux

I downloaded utorrent and spotify from the AUR packages. Because of that I also had to install wine, but I couldn't manage to delete them,  instead I deleted wine as a workaround and remove utorrent's and spotify's directories.

What is the *right way* to  do it? Anything I'm missing?

Comment: The correct way to remove packages, supported or otherwise (AUR), is with `pacman -R`...

Comment: But I couldn't find neither spotify nor utorrent as installed packages but could run them with wine.

Comment: Your question isn't clear: did you install utorrent and spotify using `makepkg` and `pacman` or through `wine`? If the latter, I have no idea...

Comment: I used makepkg and pacman

Comment: Then both files will be tracked in pacman's database and you can use pacman to remove them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct way to delete a package is `pacman -R package-name`.  To delete everything, including modified configuration files and dependencies you may have pulled in with a tool such as `yaourt` or `packer`, run `pacman -Rns package-name`.

In this respect, AUR packages are no different from native packages.