# Does Pacman's "-n" flag purge configuration files for AUR packages?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, uninstall, aur

In Pacman's man page, there is a `-n` (nosave) flag that purges all the configuration files of the package being removed.  Does this flag work for packages installed from AUR?  Is manual cleanup required for packages build from AUR?

Answer (score 1):

Pacman's `-n` flag purges configuration files for packages installed from AUR. Pacman handles both the packages of official repositories as well as AUR in the same manner.

During search, I found the answer here : [What should I consider when deleting an AUR package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209041/what-should-i-consider-when-deleting-an-aur-package/218762)

> The correct way to delete a package is `pacman -R package-name`. To delete everything, including modified configuration files and dependencies you may have pulled in with a tool such as yaourt or packer, run : `pacman -Rns package-name`. In this respect, AUR packages are no different from native packages.

Also, I found a similar answer in this article as well : https://averagelinuxuser.com/which-aur-helper-yay/#remove-a-package

> You can also remove an installed AUR program and its dependencies with Pacman:
> `pacman -Rns package_name`